# Sharepoint 2013 provider hosted app with claim base authentication

Tags: sharepoint-addin, adfs, provider-hosted-app

- We have Sharepoint 2013 single server farm  - **Server 1**
- another one server with ADFS 2.0 - **Server 2**
- MVC webapplication (hosted in iis) -  **Server 3 - Remote Computer**

We are using Sharepoint 2013 Provider hosted app.

**CASE 1:**
Provider Hosted App is getting installed successfully with Windows Authentication on SharePoint 2013 site. This is working fine.

**Case 2:**

We have configured ADFS 2.0 for authenticating users. 
ADFS 2.0 is successfully installed and configured. Users are getting authenticated. After configure claim base authentication we are also able to login with adfs user into our sharepoint site and authenticate users.

However, **Issue is**

- Now whenever we deploy our provider hosted app with this SharePoint site from visual studio 2012 it will give an error.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action.>

- another way we have added app package file  into our app catalog then try to add an app from app catalog it is ask for trust and then can not able to redirect our provider hosted app
  Sharepont Log file Error

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/appInv.aspx, Error=This App is not installed on this site. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.SprocWrappers.GetAppInstanceById(SqlSession dbSessionWrapper, Guid siteId, Guid webId, Guid instanceId, Int32 lcid) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppCatalog.GetAppInstance(SPWeb web, Guid appInstanceId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppInvPage.SetControlStateUsingAppInstanceId(String appInstanceId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppInvPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action.>"

for this error you need to change your system account

Go to **Central admin-> Security -> Configure Service account -> select your web application pool in drop-down  - > in account drop-down you need change any other instead of current log-in user**

simply we need to **change web application pool identity.**

That's it,

Thanks,
Jatin Ambaliya